# Phonegap Sqlite Error processing SQL : 6

Tags: sqlite, cordova

I'm French so sorry for my bad english, I need some help, I'm trying to copy my database on my webserver into my phonegap application for make a local database, so I've this :

```
function dlDatabase(){
        var db = window.openDatabase("Databases", "1.0", "Cordova Demo", 200000);
        db.transaction(createAllTables, errorCB, dlCountry);
    }


    function createAllTables(tx){
        tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Country (id integer primary key, name text, nbQuestion integer)');
        tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Question (id integer primary key, text text, CountryId integer)');
        tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Answer (id integer primary key, QuestionId integer, text text, isGood boolean)');
    }

    function insertCountry(tx, id, name, number){
        tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO Country(id, name, nbQuestion) VALUES (?,?,?)", [id, name, number]);
    }

    function dlCountry() {
        alert("dlCountry");
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,     
            dataType: "json",
            data : {
                actionname : 'dlCountry'
            },
            success: function(data) {
                arrayCountry = data.arrayCountry;
                var db = window.openDatabase("Databases", "1.0", "Cordova Demo", 200000);
                db.transaction(function(tx){
                    for (var i = 0; i < arrayCountry.length; i++) {
                        alert(arrayCountry[i].id+" "+arrayCountry[i].name+" "+arrayCountry[i].number);
                        insertCountry(tx, arrayCountry[i].id, arrayCountry[i].name, arrayCountry[i].number);
                    };
                }, errorCB, dlQuestion);
            },
            error: function(data) {
                alert("error !");
            }
        });
    }
```

I call the dlDatabase function when i login, that's work, but, after insert all the countries ( after the alert ), I've an error code 6 :

```
function errorCB(err) {
    alert("Error processing SQL: "+err.code);
}
```

I'm a beginner in SQLite, what is the error code 6, and how to solve it ?
Thank you for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

First off all, change `alert("Error processing SQL: "+err.code);` to `alert("Error processing SQL: "+err.message);`.

Like it is described inside the cordova/phonegap documentation...

> The SQLError object is thrown when an error occurs when manipulating a
>   database.

This object has two properties:

- code (one of your described constants)
- **message: A description of the error**.

Detailed answer to this thing can be found here -> [How to show useful error messages from a database error callback in Phonegap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13689006/how-to-show-useful-error-messages-from-a-database-error-callback-in-phonegap)

Like you can see in that link, Error-Code 6 means

> CONSTRAINT_ERR = 6

Information about the constraint error can be found here -> http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_constraints.asp i'm going to inspect your code now. As far as i'm having the answer to your specific problem, i'm going to edit. So far, for your information.

Comment: Ok, I've the message, it's :" could not execute statement due to a constraint failure (19 constraint falied) "